# Why don't we take activities in the rate law?

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics

I am slightly confused by the fact that concentrations and not activities are taken in the rate law which is different to equilibrium and seems to lead to a discrepancy. For example, for the reaction $aA(g)+bB(aq)+cC(g)⇌eE(g)+fF(aq)+gG(aq)$, the value of $K_{eq}$ is:- $$K_{eq} = \frac{(P_{\ce{E}})^e[\ce{F}]^f[\ce{G}]^g}{(P_{\ce{A}})^a[\ce{B}]^b(P_{\ce{C}})^c}$$

where all quantities are dimensionless.The above expression follows from the definitions of activities of gases and solutes.

Now, the rate law for the forward reaction will be $v_f= K_{fwd} [A]^a[B]^b [C]^c$ and for the backward reaction will be $v_b= K_{bwd} [E]^e [F]^f[G]^g$ where [X]=$ \frac{P_x}{RT}$. Since, at equilibrium, $v_f=v_b$, so  $K_{fwd} [A]^a[B]^b [C]^c=K_{bwd} [E]^e [F]^f[G]^g$. Since $K_{eq}$=$\frac{K_{fwd}}{K_{bwd}}$ so we have $$K_{eq} = \frac{[{\ce{E}}]^e[\ce{F}]^f[\ce{G}]^g}{[\ce{A}]^a[\ce{B}]^b[{\ce{C}}]^c}$$

which is incorrect. So, do we take activities in the rate law(and concentration is a common misquotation) or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Try to use activities instead of concentration.

Comment: @Poutnik That was what I suspected but many texts say to take concentration. Is it a common misquotation?

Comment: It is rather empirical pragmatism. It is **much** easier to use concentrations.

Comment: Expressions with activities are exact, but mostly unusable. Concentrations are often acceptable approximations.

Comment: @Poutnik Why is $v_f= K_{fwd} (P_A)^a[B]^b (P_C)^c$ unusable?

Comment: Substitute literal values for activities for solutes, or fugacities for gases. As partial pressure is similar approximation as concentration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137859/discussion-between-boson-and-poutnik).